# How to create topics and synchronize them when recording a bagfile

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag, message-filters, rosbag-record, rostopic-echo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

thanks for taking the time to check my post. So let me describe what I want to do.

- For starters I have a bag file containing a topic which carries a directory path at each message, the important part of the topic are the timestamps.
- The path leads to a video file.
- I take the frames of the video and create an image topic.
  Note there are 4 videos so the output is 4 Image topics.

The question is how to get them synchronized. I tried creating 4 topics with the same timestamp at each topic but when I recorded them they seem not to be in sync. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rosbag
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2
import message_filters

# Declare the bag file which recorded the data paths.
bag = rosbag.Bag("econ_vid_paths.bag")

'''
Initialize the node with the name "Image_publisher" and the publishers that will 
contain the image messages
'''
rospy.init_node('Image_publisher') 
cam_0_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/econ/image_raw/cam_0', Image, queue_size = 100)
cam_1_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/econ/image_raw/cam_1', Image, queue_size = 100)
cam_2_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/econ/image_raw/cam_2', Image, queue_size = 100)
cam_3_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/econ/image_raw/cam_3', Image, queue_size = 100)

# Create an object that converts between OpenCV images and ROS image messages.
bridge = CvBridge()

# Open video files.
cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture('/mnt/28007d94-f5ac-4179-b807-b9ec1cf293c7/econVideo_2021-06-11-17-13-51_0.mkv')
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture('/mnt/28007d94-f5ac-4179-b807-b9ec1cf293c7/econVideo_2021-06-11-17-13-51_1.mkv')
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture('/mnt/28007d94-f5ac-4179-b807-b9ec1cf293c7/econVideo_2021-06-11-17-13-51_2.mkv')
cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture('/mnt/28007d94-f5ac-4179-b807-b9ec1cf293c7/econVideo_2021-06-11-17-13-51_3.mkv')

# Create frame_number variable, this will work as a counter for the frames.
frame_number = 0;


for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/sync_vid_publisher/econ_vid']):
    # Take retrieve value (retX) and frames, if retX is 0 then there is no valid frame.
    ret0, frame0 = cap0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()
    ret3, frame3 = cap3.read()  

    if ret0+ret1+ret2+ret3==4: # Check if every camera has a valid frame.
        timestamp_secs = msg.header.stamp.secs
        timestamp_nsecs = msg.header.stamp.nsecs

        video_message_0 = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame0, encoding="bgr8")
        video_message_0.header.stamp.secs = timestamp_secs
        video_message_0.header.stamp.nsecs = timestamp_nsecs
        cam_0_publisher.publish(video_message_0)

        video_message_1 = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame1, encoding="bgr8")
        video_message_1.header.stamp.secs = timestamp_secs
        video_message_1.header.stamp.nsecs = timestamp_nsecs
        cam_1_publisher.publish(video_message_1)
    
        video_message_2 = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame2, encoding="bgr8")
        video_message_2.header.stamp.secs = timestamp_secs
        video_message_2.header.stamp.nsecs = timestamp_nsecs
        cam_2_publisher.publish(video_message_2)
    
        video_message_3 = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame2, encoding="bgr8")
        video_message_3.header.stamp.secs = timestamp_secs
        video_message_3.header.stamp.nsecs = timestamp_nsecs
        cam_3_publisher.publish(video_message_3)
    
        print('Frame :',  frame_number, 'published.')
        frame_number+=1
```

By doing this I thought that the topics are going to be synchronized as they have the same timestamp but when I recorded the messages and looked at the contents in rqt I noticed that they are not synchronized. Although, when I echo each timestamp from the topics (`rostopic echo /econ/image_raw/cam_1/header/stamp`) they are exactly the same. So why are they not recorded in sync ? I record them using the following: `rosbag record -b 0 /econ/image_raw/cam_0 /econ/image_raw/cam_1 /econ/image_raw/cam_2 /econ/image_raw/cam_3`. Any ideas are welcome!

P.S.: Please feel free to message me directly (in order to not go off-topic) if you have any ideas about how to improve my code and you want to share

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380612/how-to-create-topics-and-synchronize-them-when-recording-a-bagfile./) by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2021-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on 2021-06-18**:
I edited the title to make it less vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey! I did a quick search and found that topic which might be of interest for you:

https://answers.ros.org/question/318536/understanding-rosbag-timestamps/

So the comment on the answer states that

```
"The rosbag writers and readers do not look at the header timestamp within the messages, and does not guarantee that messages are ordered by those timestamps."
```

---

Originally posted by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) with karma: 89 on 2021-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on 2021-06-18**:
Thank you! Your comment got me to the solution, I know now what I should be searching and I've found [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps). Now they are indeed synchronized. Thanks again!

**Comment by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) on 2021-06-18**:
Ah perfect, good to hear!